# cached relationship entries db error

Tags: database, cache, database-error

I've been trying to clear the caches prior to running this EE upgrade but when I do I'm getting this error:

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'rel_data' in 'field list'

UPDATE pfra_relationships SET rel_data = '', reverse_rel_data = ''

Filename: libraries/Functions.php

Line Number: 1205

« Back
```

I don't think this is going to help my overall upgrade path on this project but would be good to know what's going on.

Comment: What version of EE? Pre-2.6 I assume?

Comment: yeah, it's currently running 2.5.5

Comment: And if you look at the `prfa_relationships` database table, what columns does it have?

Comment: turns out this was related to my botched upgrade process - answer to follow

Answer (score 1):

So the config file for this site had:

```
$db['expressionengine']['swap_pre'] = "pfra_";
```

when it should in fact have been

```
$db['expressionengine']['swap_pre'] = "exp_";
```

even although the db tables are all set with a prefix of pfra_